# Issue in multi fileupload object with extra json parameter in REST API in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, multipartform-data, rest

I'm creating a REST API in which accepts a JSON string with 3 different fileUpload in form data.

Here is my API controller post method

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        var obj = new SubmitReportModel();
        var enggCommentImg = new List<FileModel>();
        var concernAreaImg = new List<FileModel>();
        var remarkImge = new List<FileModel>();
        string UploadPath = ("~/Uploads/ReportsData");
        Functions.CreateIfMissing(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(UploadPath));
        foreach (var item in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
        {
            if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("jsonKey"))
            {
                var jsson = await item.ReadAsStringAsync();
                obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubmitReportModel>(jsson);
            }
            else if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("enggCommentImg"))
            {
                _ = new FileModel();
                var fileDataByteArray = await item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                FileModel objfile = await SaveFileAsync(fileDataByteArray);
                enggCommentImg.Add(objfile);
            }
            else if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("concernAreaImg"))
            {
                _ = new FileModel();
                var fileDataByteArray = await item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                FileModel objfile = await SaveFileAsync(fileDataByteArray);
                concernAreaImg.Add(objfile);
            }
            else if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("remarkImge"))
            {
                _ = new FileModel();
                var fileDataByteArray = await item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                FileModel objfile = await SaveFileAsync(fileDataByteArray);
                remarkImge.Add(objfile);
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    private async Task<FileModel> SaveFileAsync(byte[] fileDataByteArray)
    {
        string uploadPath = ("~/Uploads/ReportsData");
        var objfile = new FileModel();

        var filename = uploadPath + "/" + ApiHelper.GetTimestamp() + ".jpg";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filename), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await fs.WriteAsync(fileDataByteArray, 0, fileDataByteArray.Length).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
        objfile.Name = filename;
        objfile.Type = "jpg";

        return objfile;
    }
```

This API works fine I got JSON plus multiple files in each file object as well.

It works very well when I debug using breakpoints and parse each step using f10. But when I try it without breakpoints, it only saves the first file.

Here is how I'm calling it using Postman:

[image]

I tried the same with making it synchronous but still, I get the same result - saving only one file.

Here is my synchronous POST API code

```
    public object Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        //var filesReadToProvider =Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var filesReadToProvider = Task.Run(async () => await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()).Result;
        var obj = new SubmitReportModel();
        var enggCommentImg = new List<FileModel>();
        var concernAreaImg = new List<FileModel>();
        var remarkImge = new List<FileModel>();
        string UploadPath = ("~/Uploads/ReportsData");
        Functions.CreateIfMissing(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(UploadPath));
        foreach (var item in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
        {
            if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("jsonKey"))
            {
                var jsson = Task.Run(async () => await item.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
                obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubmitReportModel>(jsson);
            }
            else if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("enggCommentImg"))
            {
                _ = new FileModel();
                var fileDataByteArray = Task.Run(async () => await item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()).Result;
                if (fileDataByteArray.Length > 0)
                {
                    FileModel objfile = SaveFiles(fileDataByteArray);
                    enggCommentImg.Add(objfile);
                }
            }
            else if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("concernAreaImg"))
            {
                _ = new FileModel();
                var corsrnArr = Task.Run(async () => await item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()).Result;
                if (corsrnArr.Length > 0)
                {
                    FileModel objfile = SaveFiles(corsrnArr);
                    concernAreaImg.Add(objfile);
                }

            }
            else if (item.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("remarkImge"))
            {
                _ = new FileModel();
                var remarkarr = Task.Run(async () => await item.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()).Result;
                if (remarkarr.Length > 0)
                {
                    FileModel objfile = SaveFiles(remarkarr);
                    remarkImge.Add(objfile);
                }

            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    private FileModel SaveFiles(byte[] fileDataByteArray)
    {
        string uploadPath = ("~/Uploads/ReportsData");
        var objfile = new FileModel();

        var filename = uploadPath + "/" + ApiHelper.GetTimestamp() + ".jpg";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filename), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(fileDataByteArray, 0, fileDataByteArray.Length);
        }
        objfile.Name = filename;
        objfile.Type = "jpg";

        return objfile;
    }
```

I'm unable to figure what exactly wrong step I made in it as there is no error in it.

**UPDATE:**

> As theGeneral advised, I do recheck all steps and created a log so
> found that all images were getting upload within a second so all of
> them receive the same timestamp as name, and as a result, only one
> file was getting overwrite again and again.
>
> Keeping this thread as it is as this API work for files + other data
> (JSON string in my case) and may get helpful for others

Comment: So in these situations (without looking et your code) you need to invest in logging

Comment: I tried that one when i save those image i added filename in list and return back.. Im getting file list n response as well.. addionally there some edmx operation those are also working properly

Comment: Why are you calling task run and  result on an await call.

Comment: Remove all the task run ,and await everything,  make your method async

Comment: It is working well, as was testing on locale environment so all images were getting the same timestamp so it was getting overwrite the same image.